# How can I conceal a gap between a wall and newly installed vinyl flooring that I cut too short?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I cut my new vinyl flooring too short, causing a gap at one wall.  How can I cover it up?

Answer (score 3):

You can use quarter round to extend your baseboards and cover small gaps.

[image: Quarter Round]
<sub>(source: [houserepairtalk.com](http://cdn.houserepairtalk.com/attachments/f13/5082d1368845570-install-quarter-round-when-there-large-gap-underneath-baseboard-quarter-2.jpg))</sub>

If the gap is really large you can cut a new larger piece of the flooring and line it up with the current floor in order to create a hopefully invisible seam.  I think it generally looks better to have two large pieces with a seam instead of one large piece and one small piece.

Comment: Quarter round comes in a variety of sizes. You could also add a shorter baseboard to your current one for a little extra detail.

Comment: There is a specific type of molding made for use next to baseboard called "base shoe". If it offers enough coverage for the gap the base shoe can look more pleasing to the eye than the use of quarter round molding.

Comment: I know quarter round is easy to get and install but I HATE the look of it.   It hardly ever looks like it goes with the baseboard unless it is really plain.  Always thought this was an untapped market.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem: I just pulled up some flooring, ripped a new short piece for the corner and put the original piece back. If you glued, that wont work unless you are willing to scrape it out. Good luck. Not easy